# INotifyDataErrorInfo validating property of a property

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, inotifydataerrorinfo

I am developing my wpf application and using INotifyDataErrorInfo for validation. I have two classes (A & B) and one of them (A) has two instances of the other one (B). Now I want to validation the property of B from A. Is that possible using INotifyDataErrorInfo?

Here's my sample code:

```
class BaseValidation : INotifyDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // the implementaion of interface
   public void MyValidationMethod(string propertyName, Func<bool> expression, string errorMessage)
    {

     }
}

class B : BaseValidation
{
    public string MyString 
    {
         get {return _myString;}
         set {_myString = value;}
    }
}

class A : BaseValidation
{
     public B objB1;
     public B objB2

     A(){
          objB1 = new B();
          objB1.PropertyChanged += OnObjBPropertyChanged;
          objB2 = new B();
     }

     private void OnObjBPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs arg)
     {
          MyValidationMethod("objB1.MyString ", () => objB1.MyString != objB2.MyString , "Error");
     // here validation will pass if MyString are not equal
     }
}
```

I feel like I'm passing the wrong property name in the validation method. And I cannot implement this validation inside `B` since I need the data of other `B` object. I would assume this type of validation is possible, as I can assume this to be a common scenario, how can I do this?

Comment: The property names in your code snippet do not match in the first place. May be you can please rectify it? It is possible to compare and validate the values of 2 different objects.

Comment: @aks81 if it's possible do you know how?

Comment: There is one more clarification. You are using `PropertyChanged` event in `Class A`. Is your `BaseClass` implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: @aks81 yes BaseValidation also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface, updated my code